# Overflow : Scroll on Y and Visible on X

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue that I can't resolve.

[image]

I want the container to scroll on y only and the overflow should be visible on x, to display the dropdown menu.

Is this even possible ? Can you enlighten me ?

Thanks.

### EDIT

Here is a JSFiddle that represents my issue. You need to keep in mind that the dropdown menu doesn't have to move but just need to appear above the `.item` container. Hope you understand.

https://jsfiddle.net/sog1oxuq/1/

Comment: Can you show your HTML & CSS?

Comment: Did you try `overflow-x:visible`?

Comment: add snippets of the code

Comment: My post has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can add either

```
overflow-x hidden
```

or

```
overflow-y hidden
```

To your body

Comment: It does't work... I applied it to the container that scrolls and hides the dropdown menu but it's not working.

Comment: I might suggest making a fiddle, so we can  see exactly what we are working with

Answer (score 0):

Change the `overflow: scroll;` on `.item` to `overflow-y: scroll;`. Also, why the `left: 100px;` on `.dropdown-menu`? Change it to `left: 0;` and it should work fine.

[**See example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sog1oxuq/3/)

Comment: Ya it is a solution. But as I said, I want the `.dropdown-menu` to be moved on the right, that's why I put `left: 100px;`. Do you understand ?

Comment: @Alteyss Alright, well since you have a fixed `width` of `200px`, the scroll will be inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the jsfiddle so only the verical scrollbar appears:
https://jsfiddle.net/os5pqjqb/

All I did was update the CSS:

```
overflow-y:scroll
```

Comment: Ok, but did you try to click on the dropdown-menu ? I want the dropdown menu to be directly visible and not by scrolling, you see ?